# the member variable with the same name in derived class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

UPDATE: the behaviour is not template specific, so

```
struct Derived : public Base {
    OverrideFoo* m_data {new OverrideFoo()};
}
```

will do the same. so it seems m_data in Derived and m_data in Base both exist in memory layout. If we define a function in Derived,
e.g., Derived::print() { m_data->print()}, this will use m_data in Derived, however, if base function is called on derived object, it still use m_data from Base.

I was surprised with the behaviour of the following code, it prints "from foo", rather than the "from override foo". why is it like this? shouldn't the "m_data" be the type of "OverrideFoo"?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Foo {
    void print() {
        printf("from foo\n");
    }
};

struct OverrideFoo {
    void print() {
        printf("from override foo\n");   
    }
};

struct Base {
  void useData() {
      m_data->print();
  }
  Foo* m_data {new Foo()};  
};

template <class t> 
struct Derived : public Base {
    t* m_data {new t()};
};

int main()
{
    Derived<OverrideFoo> d;
    d.useData();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It still calls `Base::useData()` which calls `Foo::print()`, no?

Comment: shouldn't it call OverrideFoo::print()?

Comment: `Derived::m_data` doesn't replace `Base::m_data`. They are different member variables.

Comment: Not to mention that `m_data` (both of them) are uninitialised pointers. So this code is UB and would likely crash if the `print` method was virtual.

Comment: sorry, forgot initialize them, update the code

Comment: This question has two issues: 1. symbol name resolution (field). 2. Understanding how member functions are called (symbol name resolution - functions) and why virtual function is needed.

Comment: You do not have to duplicate `m_data`. `Derived` already inherits `m_data` from `Base`. You should have reassign this one instead of recreating a second one.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `d.useData()`, you are calling `Base::useData()`, which accesses `Base::m_data`.

I suppose you're expecting `Base::useData()` to use `Derived::m_data`, just because the variable has a similar name. However that's not how this works. Both classes get their own independent `m_data`, and in your case, with different types.

It's true that `Derived::m_data` *hides* `Base::m_data`, which may suggest to you that they are related or that one "overrides" the other. Don't confuse that with *hiding*. The hiding is a natural consequence of the similar naming. If `Derived` needs to access `Base::m_data`, it must qualify it in order to disambiguate from its own `m_data`.

Note: Member variables / fields cannot be overridden. If you need an override-style behavior, you'll need to do it via a member function (something like `virtual IPrintable* GetPrintable()`. And the base class must grant the possibility of overriding with the `virtual` keyword.

Another way to think about this: `Base`, despite what its name suggests, is a complete type. You can do `Base x;` to instantiate and use this class, without being derived. The compiler generates code for `Base` which is complete and functional, including the code to access `Base::m_data`. If `m_data` were somehow overrideable, how could this code be generated? What would `Base` understand `sizeof(*m_data)` to be, if its datatype could be overridden in some base class? How would the compiler know what `m_data` even refers to, if you're suggesting it can be changed by any class which derives it?

Another point: If members were able to be overridden by default (without the `virtual` keyword), it would cause mass chaos for base classes. Imagine writing a generic base class and risking that derived classes could unknowingly change the state of the base? Or imagine writing a derived class and being concerned about your variable naming because "well maybe a base class used the same name?"

So let's summarize the key points:

1. Fields cannot be overridden, period. It would break `sizeof()` among lots of other things (whole other topic)
2. Base classes must explicitly grant derived classes to override member functions via the `virtual` keyword.

There are probably better ways to do what you're attempting though. The most natural for me would be to specify the `Foo` type as a template parameter to `Base`.

Like this:

```
struct Foo1 {
    void print() {
        printf("from foo\n");
    }
};

struct Foo2 {
    void print() {
        printf("from override foo\n");   
    }
};

template<typename TData>
struct Base {
  void useData() {
      m_data.print();
  }
  TData m_data;
};

template <typename TData> 
struct Derived : public Base<TData> {
};

int main()
{
    Derived<Foo1> d1;
    d1.useData();
    Derived<Foo2> d2;
    d2.useData();
    return 0;
}
```

It's hard to know the best approach for you, because this is an unrealistic contrived example.

Comment: it is not the similar name, it is the same name and I expect m_data in derived is replacing m_data in base. no? if not so, why shall we need "Base"::m_data to access from the Derived class?

Comment: You need to specify `Base::m_data` from `Derived`, just to disambiguate. Even functions are not virtual by default. And variables themselves cannot be virtualized. It would cause a lot of chaos if so. (Imagine having to keep track of all the member variables of all base classes in the hierarchy!). And imagine writing a base class with the fear that any derived class could override any variable without warning. `virtual` grants permission to override functions. Variables can't, otherwise `sizeof()` would be impossible.

Comment: sorry, maybe my comments misleads discussion direction. what I solely want to ask is why m_data is still "Base::m_data" even in base class function, I expect it is "OverrideFoo" type.

Comment: Just because you expect something doesn't make it so. I explained one reason you might expect that, and why it's not so. Also I gave motivating justifications for why it would be a bad thing if it were so. Not sure what else there is to say, but happy to clarify if needed!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code out and you will find that the two `m_data` has different memory address, which means they are different variable.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Foo {
    void print() {
        printf("from foo\n");
    }
};

struct OverrideFoo {
    void print() {
        printf("from override foo\n");   
    }
};

struct Base {
  void useData() {
      m_data->print();
      std::cout << m_data << std::endl;
  }
  Foo* m_data {new Foo()};  
};

template <class t> 
struct Derived : public Base {
    t* m_data {new t()};
};

int main()
{
    Derived<OverrideFoo> d;
    d.useData();
    d.m_data->print();
    std::cout << d.m_data << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```